# Avoiding system() output when calling (date --set) in c++

Tags: c++, date

I have a server that is written in c++ and client in extjs. This program sets system date and time by calling date command as below:

```
system ("date --set cmd")
```

which cmd is date string given from user but calling this command outputs the date after setting it. I don't want to get this output. how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the output to `/dev/null` (which assumes a POSIX-like system, but that's reasonably safe since your command depends on GNU extensions to the `date` command):

```
system("date --set cmd >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

This is fine if all goes well; if there's a problem, you won't know.

Comment: when I run server side code separately that works fine but when running entire application that doesn't work!

Comment: Odd...do you have any other occurrences of `system()` in the code? Do they work in both contexts?  If they don't work, maybe the problem is 'environment' — something to do with the shell, perhaps.  If they work, that isn't the problem.  Setting the date requires root privileges — do you have root privileges in both contexts?  Are you sure you want to tinker with the system clock?